# Weblogic JMS URL to connect from Camel

Tags: java, spring, jms, apache-camel, weblogic12c

I am using WebLogic Server: 12.1.1.0, Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE and Camel 2.13.4.

I have the following configuration:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://localhost:7001</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">username</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">the_password</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But I get this message after deployment:

```
22-apr-2015 18.29.39 org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful
GRAVE: Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'CamelTest' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3://localhost:7001: Destination unreachable; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; No available router to destination]
```

How can I connect to the JMS server?

Comment: Downvoter, what is the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spring-boot I'm configuring JMS like this

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableJms
 public class JmsConfiguration implements JmsListenerConfigurer {
    ...
    // register here your jms listners
    @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners{
    ...
    }
 }
```

An then do whatever you want when you receive a message

```
 @Override
 @JmsListener(destination = "queue")
 public void processQueue(ResponseType response){

        //process message as you want
 }
```

Comment: Are you using weblogic? How do you set the connection factory? Can you please also post your Spring configuration files?

Comment: In JmsConfiguration I'm annotating the factory with @autowired,

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually using the server IP address instead of localhost in the configuration.